# toggle class conditionally in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Im trying to toggle a class of an element (the parent of the button being clicked) in Vue.js (which I've only started learning recently).

The idea is that the `disabled` class would be applied when `included` is *not* true.

I've created a toggleClass function, but even that is not being called it seems.

https://codepen.io/dagford/pen/NzQrJM

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="item" v-for="item in items" :id="item.id" :key="item.id">
        <span>{{item.amt}}</span>
        <button v-on:click="item.included = !item.included" v-on:click="toggleClass()">exclude me</buton>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="total">total: {{ itemTotal }}</div>
</div>
```

**VUE**

```
var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            items: [
                {
                    id: 'item1',
                    included: 'true',
                    amt: 10,
                    className: 'disabled'
                },
                {
                    id: 'item2',
                    included: 'true',
                    amt: 20,
                    className: 'disabled'
                },
                {
                    id: 'item3',
                    included: 'true',
                    amt: 30,
                     className: 'disabled'
                }
            ]
        },
        methods: {
            toggleClass: function () {
                if(this.included) {
                    console.log('test');

                    // code to toggle the 'disabled' class here?
                }
            }
        },

        computed: {
            itemTotal() {
                return this.items.reduce(function (sum, item) {
                    if (item.included) {
                        return item.amt + sum;
                    }

                    return sum;
                }, 0)
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Bert, but no... that was not what i was after.   I want the button always to be available to be toggled. Its is only the value  itself that i will grey-out - that is why i wanted the disabled class on the 'item' Div   (so i can grey out just the value using CSS)

Comment: So like this: https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/PaMWgJ

Comment: Yes correct @Bert!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working thanks to Timothy's suggestion, that was *almost* there. It was just missing the `.item` portion.

So it should be

```
<div v-bind:class="{ disabled:!item.included }"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div v-bind:class="{ disabled:!included }"></div>
```

Maybe try using class binding :
[doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks, but that threw an error:   invalid expression: Unexpected token ! in

    { !included: disabled }